# ServiceStack / ORM Lite - Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following POCO:

```
[Alias("Posts")]
public class Post : IReturn<Post>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int UpVote { get; set; }
    public int DownVote { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

It has a FK on my `Comment` and `Tag` entities. So I'd like to return those in my response from my service, but it says `'Invalid Column name 'Comments''` and `'Invalid Column name 'Tags''` . How do I see which Comments and Tags are attached to my Post, with ORM Lite? In EF I would simply use Include to lazy load my related table information, whats the equivalent?

### Edit

In response to the answers, I've done this:

```
public class PostFull
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my service, I return this, my entity `PostTag` is an intersection entity as my `Post` and `Tag` entities are a M:M relationship:

```
var posts = Db.Select<Post>().ToList();
var fullPosts = new List<PostFull>();

posts.ForEach(delegate(Post post)
{
    var postTags = Db.Select<PostTag>(x => x.Where(y => y.PostId == 
    post.PostId)).ToList();

    fullPosts.Add(new PostFull()
    {
        Post = post,
        Tags = Db.Select<Tag>(x => x.Where(y => postTags.Select(z => 
                   z.TagId).Contains(y.TagId))).ToList(),
        Comments = Db.Select<Comment>(x => x.Where(y => y.PostId == 
                       post.PostId)).ToList()
    });
});

return fullPosts;
```

Not sure whether its a good design pattern or not?

### Edit 2

Here are my entities:

```
[Alias("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Alias("Posts")]
public class Post
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[Alias("PostTags")]
public class PostTag
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PostTagId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Post))]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Tag))]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables in OrmLite are strictly a **1:1 mapping** with the underlying db tables.

This means all complex type properties are **blobbed** into a db text field with the property name, they're never used to auto-map to child relations as you're expecting to do here.

Here's an early answer that shows how you could [map many to many relations with OrmLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539573/85785).

Try to avoid **N+1** queries, remember that every call to `Db.x` is a remote DB query so you should ideally try to avoid any Database calls in a loop.

#### [Retrieving Posts by Many to Many Table query](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=3fb7f741e6e9de11c0ce487e161a693f)

You can use [OrmLite's support for JOINs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins) to construct a Typed query as you would in normal SQL to query by the Many to Many table and find all posts with the specified Tag:

Create and Populate Posts with Test Data

```
db.CreateTable<Post>();
db.CreateTable<Tag>();
db.CreateTable<PostTag>();

var post1Id = db.Insert(new Post { 
    CreatedBy = "gistlyn", Title = "Post 1", Body = "Body 1" }, selectIdentity:true);
var post2Id = db.Insert(new Post { 
    CreatedBy = "gistlyn", Title = "Post 2", Body = "Body 2" }, selectIdentity:true);
db.Insert(new Tag { Id = 1, Name = "A" }, 
          new Tag { Id = 2, Name = "B" });
db.Insert(new PostTag { PostId = post1Id, TagId = 1 }, 
          new PostTag { PostId = post1Id, TagId = 2 });
db.Insert(new PostTag { PostId = post2Id, TagId = 1 });
```

#### Create a SQL Expression Joining all related tables:

When following OrmLite's normal naming conventions above, [OrmLite can infer the relationship between each table](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins) saving you from specifying the JOIN expression for each query, e.g:

```
var postsWithTagB = db.Select(db.From<Post>()
                                .Join<PostTag>()
                                .Join<PostTag,Tag>()
                                .Where<Tag>(x => x.Name == "B"));
postsWithTagB.PrintDump();
```

Where this Query returns just the first Post for Tag `B` and both Posts for Tag `A`.

You can further explore this stand-alone example online by [running it Live on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=3fb7f741e6e9de11c0ce487e161a693f).

#### Populating all Posts with Tags and Comments

If this is a small blog and you want to load all the posts with their related tags and comments e.g. in a home page or RSS feed you can load the entire dataset in memory with 4 queries using Linq2Objects to join them with something like:

```
//Only 4 DB calls to read all table data
var posts = Db.Select<Post>();
var postTags = Db.Select<PostTag>();
var tags = Db.Select<Tag>();
var comments = Db.Select<Comment>();

//using Linq2Objects to stitch the data together
var fullPosts = posts.ConvertAll(post =>
{
    var postTagIds = postTags
        .Where(x => x.PostId == post.PostId)
        .Select(x => x.PostTagId).ToList();

    return new PostFull {
        Post = post,
        Tags = tags.Where(x => postTagIds.Contains(x.TagId)).ToList(),
        Comments = comments.Where(x => x.PostId == post.PostId).ToList(),
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to do `tag => tag.Contains`. tag here is an object containing an `Id` and `Name` field.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff It should be LINQ's **Any()** I've had to do it free-hand since we don't have the definition of your entities.

Comment: This approach is not scalable at all, if there are thousands of records in database, this method fails miserably

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include Tags and Comments to the Post entity. In your case your DTO and DB model classes should be different. In Tag and Comment classes you should have PostId property.

In service you should query for Comments where PostId equals your Post Id and do the same for Tags. The results should be added to your Post DTO containing lists of comments and tags.