# ServiceStack Ormlite and RowVersion support

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, rowversion

What is the easiest way to support sql server rowversion during update?

I tried this:

```cs
db.UpdateOnly(u, f => new { f.Name, f.Description, f.Modified, f.ModifiedBy }, f => f.Version == u.Version && f.Id == u.Id);
```

but that fails miserably because it compares version as a `Varchar(8000)`, go figure.

Not exactly the same but still a ServiceStack and OrmLite question:

What is the best way to eager load related entity descriptions? I've [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616516/servicestack-ormlite-how-to-include-field-from-foreign-key-lookup) but noticed the `Join` changeset being checked in?  This has lead to the POCO classes now having additional "Ignored" descriptions for each of the foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As RowVersion is a `byte[]` field, it requires a parameterized support for Updates / Insert which [have been added to ServiceStack.OrmLite in v3.9.37](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#new-parameterized-apis).

The `Join` support is apart of a new Expression builder we're planning on adding to OrmLite, it's not ready yet. For eager loading you can use custom SQL or depending on your query you may be able to [join the result sets in-memory using Linq2Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504260/85785).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I look forward to the next release then.  I will mark this as the answer for now but think it worthwhile to add a sample when it becomes available.