# How does ServiceStack ORMLite handle Many to many relationships?

Tags: orm, many-to-many, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am working on an ORMLite demo and so far, it has been doing everything I wanted it to do. However, the production DB against which we are going to work has a  lot of many to many relationships where we have a landing table with composite primary key.

I am just wondering if there is a way using which it handles Many-Many relationships so that if we have a Table A, Table B and table AB which has primary keys of table A and B as a composite primary key, how do we handle that? Do we have any sample for this kind of situation in

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit support for Many to Many relationships in OrmLite, i.e. you would handle it by creating a Poco that maps to each RDBMS table and just save each as you would normally, see this [previous answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539573/85785).